# ARM GIC Interrupt starvation

Tags: arm, interrupt, interrupt-handling

Not sure if there are similar questions.  I tried to backread but can't find any, so here it is.

In my bare-metal application that uses ARM Cortex-A9 (dual core with GIC), some of the interrupt sources are 4 FPGA interrupts (let's say IRQ ID 58, 59, 60, 61) that have the same priority and the idea is that all simultaneously trigger continuously in run-time.  I can say the interrupt handlers may qualify as long, but not very long.

All interrupts fire and are detected by GIC and all are flagged as PENDING.  The problem is, only the two higher ID'ed interrupts (58, 59) get handled by CPU, starving the other two.  Once 58 or 59 are done, their source will trigger again and grab the CPU over and over again.  My other interrupts are indefinitely being starved.

I played around with priority, assigning higher interrupts to 60 and 61.  Sure enough, 60 and 61 triggered and got handled by CPU, but 58 and 59 are starved.  So it's really an issue of starvation.

Is there any way out of here, such that the other two will still be processed given their triggering rate?

Answer (score 1):

Assuming the GIC implementation is one of ARM's designs, then the arbitration scheme for multiple interrupts at the same priority is fixed at "dispatch the lowest-numbered one", so if you were hoping it could be changed to some kind of round-robin scheme you're probably out of luck.

That said, if these interrupts are more or less permanently asserted and you're taking them back-to-back then that's a sign that you probably don't need to use interrupts, or at least that the design of your code is inappropriate. Depending on the exact nature of the task, here are some ideas I'd consider:

- Just run a continuous polling loop cycling through each device in turn. If there *are* periods when each device might not need servicing and it's not straightforward to tell, retain a trivial interrupt handler that just atomically sets a flag/sequence number/etc. to inform the loop who's ready.
- Handle all the interrupts on one core, and the actual processing on the other. The handler just grabs the necessary data, stuffs it into a queue, and returns as quickly as possible, while the other guy just steadily chews through the queue.
- If catching every single interrupt is less important than just getting "enough" of each of them on average, leave each one disabled for a suitable timeout after handling it. Alternatively, hack up your own round-robin scheduling by having only one enabled at a time, and the handler reenables the *next* interrupt instead of the one just taken.

Answer (score 0):

> In my bare-metal application that uses ARM Cortex-A9 (dual core with GIC)...

> Is there any way out of here, such that the other two will still be processed given their triggering rate?

Of course there are many ways.

1. You have a dual CPU so you can route a set to each CPU; 58/59 to CPU0 and 60/61 to CPU1.  It is not clear how you have handled things with the distributor nor the per-CPU interfaces.
2. A 2<sup>nd</sup> way is to just read the status in the 58/59 handlers of the 60/61 and do the work.  Ie, you can always read a status of another interrupt from the IRQ handler.
3. You can also service each and every pending interrupt recorded at the start of the IRQ before acknowledging the original source.  A variant of '2' implemented at the IRQ controller layer.

I believe that most of these solutions avoid needless context save/restores and should also be more efficient.

Of course if you are asking the CPU to do more work than it can handle, priorities don't matter.  The issue may be your code is not efficient; either the bare metal interrupt infrastructure or your FPGA IRQ handler.  It is also quite likely the FPGA to CPU interface is not designed well.  You may need to add FIFOs in the FPGA to buffer the data so the CPU can handle more data at a time.  I have worked with several FPGA designers.  They have a lot of flexibility and usually if you ask for something that will make the IRQ handler more efficient, they can implement it.